# Implantação do GIT

Tags: aplicação-web, git, versionamento

Trabalho em uma fábrica de sites e entre uma das ações desse semestre está a implantação do GIT.

Hoje trabalhamos da seguinte forma:

Solicitamos um servidor, instalamos o Joomla e desenvolvemos os sites em ambiente de homologação antes de liberar para acesso público.

Algumas de nossas ações são feitas após o site ter sido liberado e, por incrível que pareça, até a minha chegada à equipe, as alterações eram feitas em ambiente de produção. Daí a ideia da implementação do GIT.

Não temos acesso à SSH do servidor, por isso pensei em deploy via FTP.

Gostaria de sugestões de como adaptar a nossa rotina de desenvolvimento ao uso do GIT.

- Criar um ambiente de homologação no mesmo servidor, fazer edições e
  depois um merge?
- Criar um ambiente de desenvolvimento local?
- Qual seria o cenário ideal?

Comment: Sua pergunta é inteiramente baseada em opiniões e, por isso, é impossível de elaborar uma resposta canônica. Quanto conseguir um mínimo de 20 pontos de reputação, você poderá discutir isso lá no nosso [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).

Comment: O fluxo de trabalho quem vai decidir são vocês, recomendo o curso: [Git Completo: Do Básico ao Avançado](https://www.udemy.com/git-completo-do-basico-ao-avancado/learn/v4/overview). Assim que tiver uma noção melhor de Git vai saber como implantá-lo.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente é uma pergunta aberta a discussões.

Mas está minha contribuição, hoje trabalho com apenas 2 ambientes, homologação e produção, então você teria uma branch **homolog** e a outra seria a **master**. Caso não consiga liberação para acesso via **SSH**, continue fazendo deploy via **FTP**. Mas pelo menos você terá uma validação de implantação e também do cliente, antes de efetuar alterações em produção.

Não existe o cenário perfeito, por que cada cliente é diferente do outro. Acredito que existindo uma validação e uma entrega rápida, todo mundo ganha.

Sua ideia de criar o ambiente de homologação é ótima!

Answer (score 2):

recomendo uma **branch** para você dar **checkout** para cada desenvolvedor ou por requesitos.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, Thiago!

Concordo com a opinião do Vinicius, continue com deploys via FTP, caso ainda não tenha implementado, para fazer um deploy com GIT via FTP existe um repositório do GIT que pode te ajudar [GIT-FTP](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) e tem todo o conteúdo necessário.

Para o ponto da organização:

Utilize uma **Branch master** - É a branch que contém código em nível de produção, ou seja, o código mais maduro existente na sua aplicação. Todo o código novo produzido eventualmente é juntado com a branch master, em algum momento do desenvolvimento;

**Branch develop** - É a branch que contém código em nível preparatório para o próximo deploy. Ou seja, quando features são terminadas, elas são juntadas com a branch develop, testadas (em conjunto, no caso de mais de uma feature), e somente depois as atualizações da branch develop passam por mais um processo para então ser juntadas com a branch master;

Caso o projeto seja muito grande e possua muitas features, utilize também a organização por **Branches feature** - São branches no qual são desenvolvidos recursos novos para o projeto em questão. Essas branches tem por convenção nome começando com feature/ (exemplo: feature/new-layout) e são criadas a partir da branch develop (pois um recurso pode depender diretamente de outro recurso em algumas situações), e, ao final, são juntadas com a branch develop;

Caso tenha interesse, podes dar uma lida no [git flow](https://fjorgemota.com/git-flow-uma-forma-legal-de-organizar-repositorios-git/), recomendo.

Abraços